# meaning of 'stitlings'

Tags: meaning

> He had also thought well
>
> To comply with their wish
>
> To spend all their play-time
>
> In learning to fish
>
> For **stitlings**; they sent her
>
> A present of three,
>
> Which, fried, were a feast
>
> For Dame Wiggins of Lee.

This is part of John Ruskin's children's poem, Dame Wiggins of Lee and Her Seven Wonderful cats. I couldn't find the meaning of '**stitlings**' in nowhere. Do you think it's just a simple typo? Then what would be the original word the author intended to use here?

You can see the whole book here.

https://archive.org/details/damewigginsoflee00peariala/page/3/mode/2up

Comment: It's not a word I (native BrE speaker) have ever heard either and it's not in the dictionary I have on my desk.  But it's clear what it means, it's a kind of fish, *in learning to fish for stitlings*.  It's also clear that 3 of them made a feast so they're not terribly small, nor terribly big.  If I had read more of the poem I might also know that they are fresh- or saltwater fish, and if I knew more of Ruskin or the location of the poem I might suppose that it is a dialect word, and what dialect.  Now I know enough that it is no hindrance to continuing to read the poem.  And so do you.

Comment: Found in ['The Web of Language' – Dennis Baron, 2008](https://blogs.illinois.edu/view/25/4641): The OED records 1,248 other English words first appearing in 1425 – an average of one new word every 7 hours.  These include keepers like accusation, donation, macaroon, peacemaker, and upset, as well as words that quickly fell by the wayside (c. 1400) like dissemblation, mortificative, peacockly, plet, _stitling_, and wontsomeness.